# Add text labels in opencv image

Tags: c++, opencv, label

I have got an image in opencv, and I want to add labels in the axis. Actually I want similar implementation as xlabel and ylabel matlab functions. How is it then, to add labels in both x and y axis of an image?

Comment: if you know where to print the labels you can  use `cv::putText` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a string a label variable `label` image matrix `img` and positions `x` and `y` , you can do

```
putText(img, label, Point(x, y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
```

The additional parameters are for font attributes.

Comment: Is not actually what I want. I want to imwrite image with labels in x and y axis without painting in pixels of the original image.

Comment: Make a copy with img.clone() then modify the copy.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the size of the original image and then create a new image that is larger than the existing image from this, manually draw your Axis in this image, and label them using the putText function. Then insert the original image into the relevant portion of this new image.

Images dont have "Axis" as such, so your labels and axis will need to be part of the image!